# How to add line break in rdoc

Tags: ruby, rdoc

I have a code and comments for `RDoc` like this:

```
# first line comment
# second line comment
def foo
end
```

When I output document by `rdoc foo.rb`, then line break are ignored in HTML file.

To add line break I can write like:

```
# first line comment<br>
# second line comment
```

or

```
# first line comment
#
# second line comment
```

but I feel both way are not simple enough.

Is there other simple way to add line break in `RDoc`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add two or more spaces to the end of the line and it will work.

```
#first comment  
#second comment
def foo
end
```

The first line has 2 spaces after `comment`.

Answer (score 0):

Add answer regarding add line break in common text:
Make heading with full white space

```
　＂=== 　＂　# <= the quoted part
```

At least this works on github.